# Finding energy density current for free particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity, topological-field-theory

I'm trying to find the energy current operator for a topological superconductor, using the continuity equation $\frac{d\mathcal{H}(x)}{dt} = -\partial_x J_E(x)$. First, however, I would like to get the simple case of a free particle system, Where the Hamiltonian density is: $\mathcal{H}(x) = \psi^\dagger(x) \frac{p^2}{2m}\psi(x)$. The full Hamiltonian takes the form: $H = \int dx' \mathcal{H}(x')$.

The main problem I encounter is that the final result is non-hermitian, although the time derivative of a hermitian operator should also be hermitian.

I start by representing the the field operators in momentum space, as $\psi(x) = \sum_k e^{ikx} c_k$, which results in:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H}(x) = \sum_{qq'}\frac{q^2}{2m}e^{i(q-q')x} c^\dagger_{q'} c_q
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
H = \int dx'\mathcal{H}(x') = \sum_{k}\frac{k^2}{2m}c^\dagger_{k} c_k
\end{equation}

Now using Heisenberg's equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d \mathcal{H}(x)}{dt} = i[H,\mathcal{H}(x)] = i\sum_{kqq'}\frac{k^2 q^2}{(2m)^2} [c_k^\dagger c_k, c^\dagger_{q'}c_q]e^{i(q-q')x}
\end{equation}

No matter how I continue from here I cannot obtain a hermitian result.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathcal{H}(x)$ is not Hermitian:

$$\mathcal{H}(x)^\dagger=\sum_{qq'} \frac{q^2}{2m}e^{i(q'-q)x}c_q^\dagger c_{q'}$$

thus exchanging $q \rightleftharpoons q'$ except for the factor $q^2$.

Comment: I see your point, but i think you forgot to exchange the index at the energy prefactor $q^2 \rightarrow q'^2$. If im not mistaken this is an expression which is non hermition.

Comment: Yeap, sorry, indeed. I corrected my answer and I will keep thinking about it…